# popup message box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, popup

I am new to `JQuery` . I need to popup message box using `JQuery`. Please help how to do it or please provide me the link how can i obtain this.

I was using messi but i am unable get the required result.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/messi.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="files/messi.min.js">    
      new messi('This is a message with Messi.', { title: 'Title' });
    </script>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="click" />
     </div>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is messi here? Is it a jquery plugin that you are using?

Comment: @ryadavilli ya refered this https://github.com/marcosesperon/Messi

Answer (score 6):

You can **easily done it by** using **jQuery Ui.**

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" id="contactUs">Contact Us</a>                   
 <div id="dialog" title="Contact form">
   <p>appear now</p>
 </div>
```

You need to **initialize the Dialog**

```
$(function() {
  // this initializes the dialog (and uses some common options that I do)
  $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen : false, modal : true, show : "blind", hide : "blind"});

  // next add the onclick handler
  $("#contactUs").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

**Great Links for Dialog popups** [**Link 1**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)
Another one [**Link 2**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default)

I got this from [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867077/jquery-dialog-popup)

Hope this will help.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
and solved by using `Ajax Control Toolkit` to popup messagebox.

And you can find an example here for `ModelPopupExtender` :
http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-use-ASPNET-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ModalPopup.aspx
You can customize this. And can also popup the message box by codebehind manually.

Regards, Bengi.