# Modal jquery popup window razor view

Tags: jquery, razor

I have been trying for a while, need a modal jQuery popup window in razor partial view for each link. Here is my attempt. Once I click on the link it re-direct to the page `home/test/1` instead of a popup window.

then in my `Test.cshtml`  inside div with id `"dialog-view"`   `@ViewBag.id`

in controller and `about.cshtml` view are below.  Please help me out.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
           return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult Test(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.id = id;
            return PartialView();
        }
    }




 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  @Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Test", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "viewDialog" })
     @Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Test", new { id = 2 }, new { @class = "viewDialog" })


    <div id="dialog-view"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".viewDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            //can see usl
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            alert(url);
            $("#dialog-view").dialog({
                title: 'View Modal',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 355,
                width: 400,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                  $(this).modal('show');

                },
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-view").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

       </script>
```

Comment: did you check console errors in browser?

Comment: there are no errors. is there any special step I need to enter to test it? Also are the file correctly included?

Comment: also what needs to be included in my Test.cshtml ? I just have 1 div dialog-view

Comment: first of all just try to check that your jquery click event work or not that page?

Comment: how? if  I move alert url after  line $("#dialog-view").dialog({ it does not work. But before it, I get the alert window.

Comment: Please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867077/jquery-dialog-popup

Comment: this is not mvc partial view sample

Comment: which mvc are you use?

Comment: ooh.. this is Asp.net mvc structure.I thought tgat this Php mvc structure. I really don't know Asp.net. I am Really sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Needed to comment jquery in layout and update the code. This works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 @Html.ActionLink("Link3", "Test", null, new { id = 234 }, new { @class = "modal" })
  @Html.ActionLink("Link4", "Test", null, new { id = 34 }, new { @class = "modal" })

            <div id="dialog" title="form">      
            </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $('.modal').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```